# Uso de *args y **kwargs en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones

He visto ejemplos de código en los que las funciones reciben parámetros `*args` y `**kwargs`. No entiendo esa sintaxis ni en qué casos debe usarse.

Aunque he intentado leer al respecto, sólo he encontrado información en inglés que no he entendido **¿alguien podría explicármelo en español en pocas palabras?**

Comment: https://blog.carreralinux.com.ar/2017/07/args-y-kwargs-python-significado/

Comment: Tu "pregunta" se responde con una sencilla búsqueda en Google.

Comment: Como bien dice @abulafia, considera editar la pregunta y reformularla de una manera mas "formal". Un saludo

Answer (score 14):

Las funciones en python pueden recibir parámetros de dos diferentes tipos: los que al invocar la función se asignan por la posición que ocupan en la lista de parámetros, y los que al invocar se asignan por el nombre del parámetro.

Por ejemplo, considera la siguiente función con cinco parámetros. Los dos primeros no tienen valores por defecto, los tres últimos sí:

```py
def ejemplo(a, b, c=1, d=0, e=2):
    print("He recibido a={}, b={}, c={}, d={}, e={}".format(a,b,c,d,e))
```

Si la invocamos así: `ejemplo(10, 20)`, estaremos usando el método posicional, de modo que `a` tomará el valor `10` y `b` el valor `20`. Los restantes parámetros tomarán el valor por defecto especificado en la declaración de la función. También podemos invocarla así: `ejemplo(10, 20, 30)`, en ese caso el `30` irá a `c`, puesto que posicionalmente es el tercer parámetro.

Pero también podemos invocarla así: `ejemplo(b=20, a=10, d=4)`. En este caso el orden en la invocación no importa, ya que estamos usando los nombres de los parámetros para especificar a qué parámetro va cada valor. Eso sí, obligatoriamente tenemos que asignar valores a `a` y `b` ya que no tienen valor por defecto en la declaración de la función.

Pero hay ocasiones en las que no sabemos de antemano cuántos parámetros va a recibir la función. Un caso típico es cuando la función en cuestión recibe como parámetro otra función que debe invocar, junto con los parámetros que hay que pasarle a esa otra función. Este tipo de función "envoltorio" de otra se usa mucho en decoradores.

No voy entrar todavía en el tema de la función envoltorio. En su lugar simplemente plantéate que tienes una función que pueda invocarse con diferente número de parámetros y no sabes de antemano cuántos.

Para esto Python ofrece la posibilidad de declarar un único parámetro en la función con un asterisco delante. Es costumbre llamar `*args` a ese parámetro, pero en realida puedes llamarlo como quieras. Lo que ocurrirá es que ese parámetro será una *tupla* con todos los argumentos que le hayas pasado en la función durante la llamada. Así, por ejemplo:

```py
def ejemplo2(*args):
   print("He recibido estos parámetros: `, args)
```

Esta función imprimirá la tupla que recibe como parámetro. Puedes invocar esa función así: `ejemplo2(1,2,3)` e imprimirá `"He recibido estos parámetros: (1, 2, 3)"`.

No obstante, si intentas llamar a la función usando la sintaxis de asignar, por ejemplo así: `ejemplo2(a=1, b=2, c=3)`, fallará, ya que el asterisco de `*args` indica que esa variable recogerá todos los parámetros *posicionales*, pero no recogerá ninguno no-posicional. De hecho la declaración de `ejemplo2()` impide que le pases parámetros no-posicionales.

Para lo segundo está la sintaxis con doble asterisco. Si precedes un parámetro con `**`, ese parámetro recogerá todos los argumentos que se le hayan pasado a la función de forma no-posicional (con nombre), en un sólo dato de tipo diccionario. En ese diccionario las claves son los nombres de los parámetros. Típicamente a este otro parámetro se le llama `**kwargs`, pero el nombre de nuevo podría ser otro.

Así, el siguiente ejemplo:

```py
def ejemplo3(*args, **kwargs):
    print("He recibido estos parámetros posicionales:", args)
    print("Y estos no posicionales:", kwargs)
```

Puede invocarse de muchas formas. Pongamos por ejemplo: `ejemplo3(1, 2, a=20, b=12)`. En ese caso por pantalla saldría:

```py
He recibido estos parámetros posicionales: (1, 2)
Y estos no posicionales: { 'a': 20, 'b': 12 }
```

Para terminar de completar el puzzle, sólo queda decir que la sintaxis `*` o `**` también la puedes usar en la invocación de una función para "expandir" una tupla o un diccionario y convertirlo en una serie de argumentos para pasarle a la función. Esto puedes hacerlo *al llamar* a otra función con independencia de que esa otra función haya usado `*`, `**`  en su declaración o haya usado la forma "normal" de declarar parámetros.

Considera por ejemplo la función `ejemplo` del principio. Puedo invocarla también así:

```py
posicionales = (10, 20)
no_posicionales = { 'c': 30, 'd': 40 }
ejemplo(*posicionales, **no_posicionales)
```

El primer `*` expandirá la tupla `(10, 20)` para rellenar dos argumentos de la función. El `**` que viene luego expandirá el diccionario para suministrar parámetros adicionales con nombre. La llamada por tanto equivale a:

```py
ejemplo(10, 20, c=30, d=40)
```

Gracias a esto se puede hacer una función que reciba otra como parámetro, junto con los argumentos que deben pasarse a esa otra, todo ello sin que la función "envoltorio" sepa de antemano la declaración de la función "envuelta".

Ejemplo:

```py
def envoltorio(funcion_a_ejecutar, *args, **kwargs):
    print("Ejecuto la función dada")
    r = funcion_a_ejecutar(*args, **kwargs)
    print("Que ha retornado", r)
    return r
```

Y puedo usarla así:

```py
envoltorio(ejemplo, 1, 2, d=40)
```

de modo que `envoltorio` recibirá la tupla `(1,2)` en `args` y el diccionario `{'d':40}` en `kwargs`, y cuando ejecute la función interna volverá a expandir esa tupla y diccionario en los argumentos apropiados, de modo que en este caso ejecutará `ejemplo(1,2,d=40)`.