# ¿Que diferencia hay entre un argumento de tipo keyword y uno de tipo non keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Para pasar un numero variable de argumentos por una función en python se usa (*args), esto es para argumentos de tipo keyword, y para argumentos tipo no keyword se usa (**kwargs), ¿que diferencia hay entre uno y otro tipo y por que se usan diferentes palabras clave?

Comment: Kilex puedes verificar este enlace https://j2logo.com/args-y-kwargs-en-python/#:~:text=Las%20principales%20diferencias%20con%20respecto,de%20los%20par%C3%A1metros%20no%20importa. recuerda que Google lo sabe casi todo si lo sabes buscar... Aqui tienes otro enlace https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/argumentos-args-kwargs/

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Uso de \*args y \*\*kwargs en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/198044/uso-de-args-y-kwargs-en-python)