# Que significa estos parametros *args, **kwargs en python?

Tags: python, django

Estaba viendo unos codigos y la verdad que  no sé muy bien que significa esos parametros escritos.

```
class StaffRequireMixin(object):
    def dispatch (self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_staff:
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('admin:login'))
            return super(StaffRequireMixin, self).dispatch(request,args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Uso de \*args y \*\*kwargs en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/198044/uso-de-args-y-kwargs-en-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando tengas que pasar argumentos a una función y no sepas cuantos, usa *args luego recorre la variable args para usarlos. Son argumentos posicionales.

```
def sum(*args):
    value = 0
    for n in args:
        value += n
    return value
```

El parámetro *args recibe los argumentos como una tupla.

Si no sabes cuantos argumentos vas a necesitar y quieres darles nombre a esas variables usarás **kwargs. Son argumentos con nombre.

```
def print_values(**kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        print("The value of {} is {}".format(key, value))


name_1="Alex",
name_2="Gray",
name_3="Harper",
name_4="Phoenix",
name_5="Remy",
name_6="Val"
```

El parámetro **kwargs recibe los argumentos como un diccionario.