# ¿Por qué en los decoradores se debe utilizar un result?

Tags: python, decoradores

Los decoradores por lo que tengo entendido son una función que toma como parámetro otra función y da como resultado otra funcion (espero no estar equivocado ya de primera mano).

Entonces, digamos que `a(b)--> c`... ahora en su sintaxis, ¿Por qué es importante poner un `result = funcion_b(*args, **kwargs)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Estás en lo correcto respecto a lo que es un decorador.

El uso de `*args` y `**kwargs` no está directamente relacionado con los decoradores, pero suele verse mucho en ellos. Esta sintaxis típicamente se usa para declarar funciones en las que no quieres especificar de antemano cuántos parámetros va a recibir ni los nombres de cada uno, pues es posible que a veces te llamen con un número de parámetros y otras veces con un número diferente.

### Explicación de `*args`

Cuando declaras en una función un parámetro `*args` significa que cuando esta función sea invocada, todos los parámetros posicionales irán a parar a ese único parámetro `args` que será una tupla.

Por ejemplo:

```
def ejemplo(*args):
   print("He recibido", len(args), "parámetros")
   print("que son:", args)
```

Esa función la puedes llamar con un parámetro, dos, tres, o los que quieras (incluso sin parámetros). Todos los parámetros que le pases los recibirá en una tupla que hemos llamado `args` (el nombre en realidad es irrelevante, lo importante es el asterisco que tiene delante). Dentro de la función podemos usar `len(args)` para averiguar cuántos parámetros recibió, y `args[0]` para acceder al primero, etc.

Ejemplo de ejecución de la función anterior:

```
>>> ejemplo()
He recibido 0 parámetros
que son: ()

>>> ejemplo(1)
He recibido 1 parámetros
que son: (1,)

>>> ejemplo(1, 2)
He recibido 2 parámetros
que son: (1, 2)
```

Por otro lado la sintaxis `*args` no sólo puedes usarla en la declaración de la función, sino también al invocar a una función. En este caso verías algo así: `resultado = funcion(*params)`.

Esta sintaxis es válida si `params` es iterable (por ejemplo una tupla o una lista). El operador `*` delante produce el *desempaquetado*, es decir, que Python iterará sobre los elementos de `params` y convertirá cada uno de ellos en un parámetro separado.

Así, si `params = (5, 7, 2)` entonces `funcion(*params)` equivale a `funcion(5, 7, 2)`. Observa que no se está pasando una lista o tupla a la función, sino tres parámetros separados. La función podría tener una declaración normal, por ejemplo así:

```
def funcion(a, b, c):
   return(a+b+c)
```

o podría también tener una declaración que use `*args`, por ejemplo así:

```
def funcion(*args):
   return sum(args)
```

En este segundo caso, la llamada `funcion(5, 7, 2)` (o si quieres `funcion(*params)` que sería lo mismo), causará que `args` contenga la tupla `(5,7,2)`. Es decir, al poner `*params` en la invocación se *desempaqueta* esa tupla para pasarla como tres argumentos separados, pero ya que la función fue declarada con `*args`, esos tres argumentos *se empaquetan otra vez* en la tupla `args` que es la que la función recibe.

Esto es útil cuando quieres hacer una función que va a llamar a otra, pero no sabes de antemano cuántos parámetros va a recibir la otra. Por ejemplo:

```
def llamar_a_funcion(funcion_a_llamar, *args):
  print("Llamando a la funcion")
  funcion_a_llamar(*args)
```

Ahora podemos invocarla así:

```
>>> llamar_a_funcion(ejemplo, 5, 6, 10)
Llamando a la funcion
He recibido 3 parámetros
que son: (5, 6, 10)
```

Los parámetros `5, 6, 10` que pasamos son recibidos por `llamar_a_funcion` dentro de la tupla `args`, y son usados para pasárselos a otra función, usando el desempaquetado. Así, mi función `llamar_a_funcion()` puede recibir como primer parámetro una función cualquiera, sin tener que saber de antemano cuántos parámetros recibirá, y puede invocarla pasándole los parámetros que se le digan.

Esta es la idea usada en los decoradores, ya que un decorador será usado para decorar diferentes funciones, cada una con un número posiblemente distinto de parámetros.

### ¿Y `**kwargs`?

Por no alargar más la respuesta, que ya es bastante larga, baste decir que el doble asterisco `**` marca otro parámetro de estos que "agrupa" muchos otros parámetros a priori desconocidos, pero en este caso se usa para los parámetros especificados mediante un nombre en la llamada (o *keyword arguments*, de ahi lo de kwargs).

Por ejemplo, si al llamar a una función haces `funcion(x=2, y=3)` estarías pasando dos *keyword arguments*, de nombres `x` e `y`. Este tipo de argumentos no son recogidos en `*args`, que recoge sólo los argumentos "sin nombre". Para recoger los argumentos "con nombre" se usa el doble asterisco.

En este caso quedan recogidos en un diccionario en vez de una tupla. Las claves del diccionario son los nombres de esos argumentos y los valores del diccionario son los valores de los argumentos.

El operador `**` también puede usarse en una llamada para *desempaquetar* un diccionario en una serie de *keyword arguments*.

Combinando `*args` y `**kwargs` puedes recibir y usar cualquier número de argumentos, tanto sin nombre como con nombre.

## Entonces, respondiendo a tu pregunta

¿Por qué dentro del decorador se ve una línea como esta?

```
result = funcion_b(*args, **kwargs)
```

Pues porque generalmente la misión de un decorador es hacer algo **adicional** a lo que ya hacía la función `b` original. Extenderlo de algún modo. Por ejemplo, supongamos que queremos que el decorador cronometre cuánto tarda en ejecutarse la función `b`, y lo imprima por pantalla. Para ello obviamente debe ejecutar la función en cuestión pasándole los mismos parámetros que el decorador haya recibido, y **debe recoger** el resultado, para poder retornarlo a su vez. Así, "desde fuera" cuando se llama a la función decorada se obtiene el mismo resultado que si se hubiera llamado a la función sin decorar.

Veamos un ejemplo. Quiero hacer un decorador que haga lo antes dicho, o sea, cronometrar a otra función:

```
import time

def cronometra(f):
  def envoltorio(*args, **kwargs):
      print("Voy a ejecutar ", f)
      antes = time.time()
      resultado = f(*args, **kwargs)  # <--- llamada a la original
      despues = time.time()
      print("La ejecución ha tardado", despues-antes, "segundos")
      return resultado
  return envoltorio
```

Una vez tenemos el decorador escrito, lo podemos aplicar a una función:

```
@cronometra
def suma(a, b):
  return a+b
```

Y cuando invoquemos a esa función, se ejecutará en realidad la versión decorada, pero ya que la versión decorada invoca a la original, se realizará a fin de cuentas el mismo cálculo:

```
r = suma(3, 6)
```

Eso dejará en `r` el resultado 9. Y además veremos por pantalla algo como:

```
Voy a ejecutar  <function suma at 0x7fc1a530fd90>
La ejecución ha tardado 1.430511474609375e-06 segundos
```

En `r` obtenemos 9 gracias a que internamente en el decorador había la línea `resultado = f(*args, **kwargs)`, que llamó a la función `suma()` original pasándole 3 y 6 (que estaban en `args`) y recogiendo el resultado de esa función, para al final, después de imprimir los tiempos, hacer un `return resultado` de modo que el 9 llegue a quien invoque la función decorada.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, de todos modos ¿no podría juntarse con [Uso de *args y **kwargs en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/198044/83) en lo referido no a los decoradores sino al uso de args/kwargs en particular?

Comment: Buenas, no sé usar muy bien todavia la pagina, la respuesta me sirvió de mucho para entender los args y kwargs, pero mi pregunta no era esa, no sé por que se eidtó sola... no se como funciona, en fin, yo lo que queria averiguar es sobre por qué en los decoradores debe ir un result = functionb(*args, **kwargs), mil disculpas!!

Comment: He editado la respuesta para aclarar eso. Mira el apartado final y dime si te queda alguna duda.