# Funciones con argumentos variables en PYTHON

Tags: python, funciones, diccionarios, tuplas

Tengo una duda con el tema de funciones con argumentos variables en Python.

El caso es que tengo este código

```
def listarNombres(*nombres):
    for nombre in nombres:
        print(nombre)

listarNombre("Karla","Jesus","Ignacio")
```

como salida me imprimiria todos los nombres

Por otra parte tengo este código

```
def doblar_valor(numeros):
   for i,n in enumerate(numeros):
   numeros[i]*= 2

n=[5,10,15,20] 
doblar_valor(n)
print(n)
```

la pregunta es, es necesario colocar * para pasarle variables de varios elementos a una función? ya que al parecer trabajan igual sin *, entonces eso se me confunde.

Mi otra pregunta es: si no se especifica el tipo de colección que se le va a pasar a la funcion, esta la toma como una tupla por default? refiriendo al caso del primer código

Comment: Adicional a la respuesta, este post te puede ayudar: [Uso de *args y **kwargs en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/198044/80870)

Comment: mil gracias me ayudo bastante, ya se la diferencia entre los parametros con un * y ** astericos

Answer (score 6):

La primera función recibe varios argumentos (en este caso todos son strings)
La segunda función recibe un único argumento (en este caso una lista)

Si en la primera función pasas un único argumento lista (En lugar de 3 strings) cambiará el resultado de esta:

```
def listarNombres(*nombres):
    for nombre in nombres:
        print(nombre)

listarNombres(["Karla", "Jesus", "Ignacio"])
```

Lo que imprime es:

```
['Karla', 'Jesus', 'Ignacio']
```

Ya que imprime en una nueva línea todos los argumentos enviados (El único argumento enviado es la lista que contiene los nombres)

Para la segunda función si le agregas el * imprimirá el siguiente error:

```
numeros[i] *= 2
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Esto se debe a que en este caso **numeros** (que es una tupla con todos los argumentos que se pasaron) tiene un único valor (que es la lista **n**), así mismo **numeros[i]** hace referencia a la lista de números que pasaste

La siguiente función dobla los valores de cada lista que se envía:

```
def doblar_valor_lista(*numeros):
    for lista in numeros:
        print([i * 2 for i in lista])


n = [5, 10, 15, 20]
m = [2, 4, 6, 8]
l = [3, 6, 9, 12]
doblar_valor_lista(n, m, l)
```

Resultado:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40]
[4, 8, 12, 16]
[6, 12, 18, 24]
```

En esta función, la tupla **numeros** tiene 3 valores:

- n = [5, 10, 15, 20]
- m = [2, 4, 6, 8]
- l = [3, 6, 9, 12]

Otra diferencia es que cuando se usa el * y se requiere otro argumento este se debe escribir explicitamente (Ya que todos los demás serán parte del argumento con *, por ejemplo en la siguiente función se enviarán una cantidad x de números y quiero que se multipliquen por un valor dado

```
def multiplicar_numeros(*numeros, multiplicador):

    print([i * multiplicador for i in numeros])

multiplicar_numeros(5, 10, 15, 20, multiplicador=2)
```

Si no se especifica el argumento **multiplicador** al *llamar la función* retornará un error sin importar que el argumento multiplicador tenga un valor por defecto

Caso contrario, con una función que reciba 2 argumentos: **numeros** (Una lista de números) y **multiplicador**, no retornará un error si no se especifica el valor de **multiplicador** (Porque tiene un valor por defecto)

```
def multiplicar_numeros_lista(numeros, multiplicador=2):

    print([i * multiplicador for i in numeros])


multiplicar_numeros_lista([5, 10, 15, 20])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya entendi.. uso * para parametros que no se cuantos elementos tendran y este devuelve una tupla, uso ** para parametros que tienen clave y valor y no se cuantos elementos tendra y devolvera un diccionario,  en otro caso referente al de la lista puedo declarar la misma adentro de la funcion e iterar con for